# Ethereum Web3.js: Intrinsic Gas too low

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I have been trying to send a transaction on the Ethereum testnet Rinkeby for the past few days and keep getting this error no matter how much I increase the gas to.

> "Unhandled rejection Error: Returned error: intrinsic gas too low"

The data I am sending is:

```
"0x7b22416e7377657273223a5b7b225175657374696f6e223a2231222c22416e73776572223a2234227d2c7b225175657374696f6e223a2232222c22416e73776572223a2234227d2c7b225175657374696f6e223a2233222c22416e73776572223a2234227d2c7b225175657374696f6e223a2234222c22416e73776572223a2234227d2c7b225175657374696f6e223a2235222c22416e73776572223a2234227d2c7b225175657374696f6e223a2236222c22416e73776572223a2234227d5d7d"
```

after it has been converted to a Hex.

I have added my code below.

```js
var number = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address).then(function(count) {
  console.log("Count " + count);
  var privateKey = new EthJS.Buffer.Buffer(privateKey, 'hex');
  console.log(web3.utils.toHex(finalAnswers));
  var rawTx = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count),
    to: '0xF1aA87F7058e5ABE561cCe8A466eE1CC17d69639',
    value: 0,
    data: web3.utils.toHex(finalAnswers),
    gas: 50000,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('300', 'gwei')
  };

  var tx = new EthJS.Tx(rawTx);
  tx.sign(privateKey);

  var serializedTx = tx.serialize();


  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')).on('receipt', console.log);
});
```

Comment: Change `gas: 50000` to `gasLimit: 50000`. You may have to increase the value as well (50k may not be enough).

Comment: Thank You for your reply! i got a different error " Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value" which i dont understand as i have 18 eth in the account  and keep getting the error when i set the limits to gasLimit: 10000, 
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'gwei')

Comment: Explicitly include the “from” parameter in your transaction object. If that doesn’t solve it, confirm your balance by adding a debug call to web3.eth.getBalance(). You may be connecting to a different network than you’re expecting.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're getting this error is because `gasPrice` is higher than `gasLimit`. You need to allocate more gas by setting a higher `gasLimit`.

And as @AdamKipris suggested in the comments, you should use `gasLimit:` instead of `gas:` when building your transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some of the methods has to bet set Gas Limit manually so I switch to a default gas limit for transaction. In pancakeswap reference, it is 20,000 units https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend/blob/master/src/config/index.ts#L31
You might adapt the prop to `gas` though

And the code look like this:

```
const txReceipt = await callWithGasPrice(
                  wethContract,
                  "deposit",
                  undefined,
                  {
                    value: `0x${inputAmount.raw.toString(16)}`,
                    gasPrice,
                    gasLimit: DEFAULT_GAS_LIMIT,
                  }
                );
```