# Ethers.js sending a transaction to a smart contract gives 'intrinsic gas too low'

Tags: javascript, typescript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I'm fairly new to blockchain and I'm struggling with sending a transaction to a smart contract - I'm getting *intrinsic gas too low* error. I've tried searching online for a solution but just couldn't solve it.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/71261434/20453413 I understand that I need to *'allocate more gas by setting a higher gasLimit'*, okey, but by how much? Am I calculating gasPrice correctly?

I've deployed my contract to a goerli testnet and I'm using Infura as a provider to the blockchain.

```
    let baseNonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(wallet.getAddress());
    const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice()

    const tx = await someContract.populateTransaction.setFoo('hello');
    tx.nonce = baseNonce + 1
    tx.value = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.001', 'ether')
    tx.gasPrice = gasPrice

    await wallet.signTransaction(tx).then(signedTransaction => {
      provider.sendTransaction(signedTransaction).then(transactionResponse => {
        console.log("Our transaction response: " + transactionResponse)
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

`provider.getGasPrice()` returns a `BigNumber` object. Something like this `{ BigNumber: "21971214174" }`

But you need to convert this BigNumber to a string. `BigNumber` object has a `toString()` to method. [you can check the docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/)

```
 tx.gasPrice = gasPrice.toString()
```

Comment: If tx is a populatedTransaction object, isn't gasPrice a BigNumber on it? I don't think I will be able to convert a string to a number.
I just don't understand what concrete values to put here honestly, but not what type of values.